# Keep textformatting with vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to use vlookup with excel and keep formatting of text?

In this case some rows that I want to copy with vlookup to another sheet is formatted with different colors. I want to keep these colors.

Comment: No - VLOOKUP will only return the values, not the formatting.

Comment: is it possible with vba? any examples?

Comment: Not with a UDF. It would have to be a macro/event code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rory pointed in comment, it is not possible to achieve it with VLOOKUP. However you can use `.Find` and `.Copy` method and probably you will receive the effect you need. Below I posted sample code. You can also use copy/paste depending on your needs.

```
Sub paste_formats()

Dim Find As String

On Error GoTo blad:
Find = Range("C3:C19").Find(Range("a1").Value).Address

Range(Find).Copy Destination:=Range("B2")

Exit Sub
blad:
If Err.Number = 91 Then: MsgBox ("Value was not found.") 'if value was not found it will pop up a message.

End Sub
```

If you want to copy rows then you just need to change a code a bit:

```
Find = Range("C3:C19").Find(Range("a1").Value).Row

Rows(Find & ":" & Find).Copy Destination:=Rows(23)
```

In case you want to only copy formatting you should use copy / pastespecial xlpasteformats.

Comment: You can place this code in a loop and change ranges with variables.